# Проблема с загрузкой папок с диска

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Проблем такая. Есть элемент TreeView, в него при загрузки формы добавляются все диски компьютера(Скриншот ниже). Когда происходит двойной щелчок по выбранному диску должны загрузиться все папки. Когда делаю двойной щелчок по "C:\" все корректно загружается, а когда по "D:\" загружаются папки диска C(диск D не пустой). Помогите решить эту проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace FileManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach(DriveInfo crrDrive in drives)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(crrDrive.Name);
            }

        }

        private void treeView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.SelectedNode.Level].Nodes.Clear();

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);

            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

            foreach(DirectoryInfo crrDir in dirs)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.SelectedNode.Level].Nodes.Add(crrDir.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас загружается папка `D` в 0-ой элемент (то есть в вашем случае в диск `C`).

Все дело в данной строке `treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.SelectedNode.Level].Nodes.Add(crrDir.Name);` - где `treeView1.SelectedNode.Level` дает глубину узла, а вам нужен индекс. Поменяйте на `treeView1.SelectedNode.Index`.

Ну а также тут `treeView1.Nodes[treeView1.SelectedNode.Level].Nodes.Clear();` тоже не забудьте поменять.